# How to print data on Angular coming from Laravel API relationship with one to many Models

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I have Angular App connected with Laravel API. In Laravel API there are one to many relationship between Employee and Salary Models. now I need print Salary Model data on Angular app. so, I try in this way

```
<div class="basic-info">
    <p>Employee Name : {{employee.first_name}}</p>
    <p>Date of Birth :</p>
    <p>Gender :</p>
    <p>Hire Date :</p>
</div> 
 <div class="salary-topic">
    <h4><b>Salary Details</b></h4>
</div>
<div class="salary-details">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">salary {{employee.salary}}</th>
                <th scope="col">From Date{{employee.from_date}}</th>
                <th scope="col">To Date{{employee.to_date}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
</div>
```

my data.service.ts is like this

```
 getEmployeeById(id: string){
    return this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee/'+id);
  }
```

and employee-by-id.ts is

```
 getData() {
    this.dataService.getEmployeeById(this.id).subscribe(res => {
     // console.log(res);
     this.data = res;
     this.employee = this.data;
    })
  }
```

my Employee model data is printing well. but relathionship Salary Model is not printing. in browser element printing both model data well in json format. how could I fix this problem?

Laravel Controller for get Employee by id

```
public function getEmployeeById($id) {
        $employee = Employee::with('titles','salaries')->find($id);
        if(is_null($employee)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee Not Found'], 404);
        }
        return response()->json($employee::with('titles','salaries')->find($id), 200);
    }
```

api route

```
//get specific employee
Route::get('employee/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@getEmployeeById');
```

**json output**

```
Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. node.js:383
Angular is running in development mode. vendor.js:47622:13
XHRGET
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee/1
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 228ms]

    
emp_no  1
birth_date  "1983-10-05"
first_name  "David"
last_name   "Koner"
gender  "male"
hire_date   "2023-09-18"
created_at  null
updated_at  null

salaries    [ {…} ]
0   Object { emp_no: 1, salary: 27000, from_date: "2023-09-22", … }
emp_no  1
salary  27000
from_date   "2023-09-22"
to_date "2023-09-19"
created_at  "2023-10-09T08:17:26.000000Z"
updated_at  "2023-10-09T08:48:02.000000Z"
```

Comment: can you show the json returned from the api?

Comment: @LuisVasquez please see I have updated my JSON output

Comment: Can you show the content of "salaries [ {…} ]"? you can get all the output of the API by directly visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee/1 from the browser if it does not require authentication or indicate the columns of the Salaries table of the database

Comment: @LuisVasquez then what should I do this?